# Как убрать пустые поля

Tags: php, html, sql

Сайт выводит из базу информацию в выпад меню,но если создать не попорядку id запись образуются пусте поля,как сделать так чтобы они скрывались или информация в базу заносилась по id и по пустым полям,если сейчас создать колонку например mtl то будет 7 id,а желательно 2 и тд
[image: БД]
[image: Сайт]

```
  for($i=1;$i<=1000;$i++)
                  {

                        $sql=mysql_query("select * from `figures` where `id`='".$i."' order by `aboutObj`");
                        while($s=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                        {
                                echo "<option value='".$s['id']."'>".$s['aboutObj']."</option>";


                        }
                        $sec=$s['id'];
                        echo "<br>";

                  }
```

Comment: какое отношение имеет колонка к id записи  ? вам наверно стоит пересмотреть структуру вашей бд.. и желательно показать ваши запросы а то не понятно чего вы хотите и что делаете..вы наверно делаете выборку всех полей(в т.ч и пустых).. в зависимости от кода в том или ином месте добавить проверку/изменить запрос нужно

Comment: @Volodymyr я хочу чтобы не было пустых строк на сайте, он отображает все то что  есть в базе т.е  7 значений id, я создал еще 3 колонки и добавил в них 1 значение в итоге отобразилось оно + 6 пустых,и если создать  7 id эти 3 колонки будут пустые строки сверху.
Ps один из запросов добавил

Comment: зачем завпрос в цикле? и проверка на id есть..`select * from `figures`  order by `aboutObj`` и зачем ето  $sec=$s['id']; ? ничего не делает

Comment: сделай проверку `if($s['mtl'] == '' && $s['objmtl'] =='' && $s['about..'] =='') continue;`

Comment: @Volodymyr у меня там дальше эта переменая передается в другой php файл из него в js